# GenexusAI, problemas para utilizar el servicio SpeechToText con Google Cloud

Tags: genexus, inteligencia-artificial

Quiero utilizar el modulo de inteligencia artificial de Genexus17, utilizando el procedimiento de SpeechToText, donde grabo un audio desde mi smart devices y se envía en el momento a transcribir.

El problema que tengo es que como proveedor tengo a Google Cloud, y solo me acepta archivos de audio con formato wav, ya que si utilizo otro formato me devuelve un error informando que espera archivos wav.
Para grabar el audio tengo un ambiente smart devices donde utilizo la función AudioRecorder, pero me graba los archivos con extención m4a.

Como puedo grabar un audio desde Genexus y utilizar SpeechToText utilizando Google si solo me acepta archivos WAV ?

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: Carlos, como estas. Si pude solucionarlo, mismo acá: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?40169,SpeechToText+procedure en la parte de "Notes" te aclara que la forma es convertir el formato del archivo a WAV, y para eso utilizas la herramienta ffmpeg. La instalas en tu S.O. y desde Genexus la usas utilizando el comando Shell para convertir el archivo a wav.